# Facebook share button not working on all pages of my website

Tags: facebook, updating, share-button

My website (www.medmennesket.dk) has a facebook-share button on most of its pages but it's only working properly on some of them.

For instance it's working on this page, http://medmennesket.dk/?page=1, but not on this one http://medmennesket.dk/?page=forside. Although a share window pops up when the button is pressed but there is no image shown and the text is from an old front page (the front page was updated recently).

The Open Graph Object Debugger doesn't show any problems (so my meta-tags must work ok) so I think it might be Facebook being slow at updating its stored data for websites, and that's why the share button on the front page makes a window pop up with old text.

Anyone got any advice on what to do or any idea what's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you could provide some code it would help people to understand the problem

Comment: Actually I just got it to work - needed to update the facebook scrape info for all the subpages and their links. Didn't think of that until just now

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `og:image` to be available on the first time the share dialog is opened for a given URL, you need to specify the correct width and height for the image, though OpenGraph `<meta>` data.

This is explained in the "Pre-caching images" in the [Sharing Best Practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) documentation:

> 2. Use `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` Open Graph tags
>    Using these tags will specify the image to the crawler so that it can render
>      it immediately without having to asynchronously.